# Calling class within jar file android

Tags: android, jar, android-intent

I create jar file containing two classes. Here I want to call the second class with the first class inside jar.

I use intent but it force close when implement these jar to another application. I provide permission in manifest too.

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,view.class);
startActivityForResult(intent,0);
```

this is my code

Comment: Post the LogCat output and be more specific on what you're trying to archive here.

Comment: the view class that you are trying to call is from the jar file , it is an activity , so make sure that you have declare it as an activity on your Manifest file int the tag <application>

Comment: yes i added activity in the manifest. I want to call another class within the jar using method having intent in main class of jar.

Comment: No command output when running: 'am start -n com.example.calldemo/com.example.calldemo.Calldemo -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER' on device emulator-5554. Its in my error log